# How to add ESLint check to WebStorm and count lines

Tags: javascript, webstorm

1. How can I add to WebStorm ESLint with some default configuration
   for Node.js project?
2. In addition, how can I count my project lines without the
   nodeModules folder?

I using WebStorm version 10.0.4

Answer (score 1):

You need to install ESLint via npm either locally in your project or globally, then go to WebStorm Preferences - Languages & Frameworks - JavaScript - Code quality tools - ESLint and Enable it. 
You would also need to add an ESLint config file (e.g. .eslintrc) to your project.
WebStorm doesn't provide any built-in functionality to count the lines in your project.